# Delay an 75 ohm rgb signal

Tags: delay, rgb

I'm looking to add a controlled amount of delay to some 75 ohm impedance RGB lines. The signal will be an AC sginal. I'm looking for about 30 ns so would something like the Maxim DS1135 be a good chip for doing this? Also do I need to terminate the line with 75 ohm resistors to ground before inputting to the delay IC? Correct me if I'm wrong but a signal with an impedance of 75 ohms and a peak to peak voltage of 1 means the signal is 13.333 mA correct?

(Edit) I need a chip because I will be using a PCB design. I will be doing some processing on one of the RGB lines which will put it 30ns behind, and so I need a 30 nanosecond delay.

Comment: You could also use some piece of cable

Comment: what length of cable should be used?

Comment: What frequency are we talking? The DS1135 (30ns variant) has a max frequency of 16MHz and min signal pulse width of 30ns.

Comment: yes the 30 ns variant. 16Mhz isn't going to cut it. I need something in the range of about 150Mhz bandwidth

Comment: 150 Mhz frequency

Comment: @UmarMahmood: Depending on the velocity factor 6-10m

Comment: Speed of light is 1nS per foot in air, and 60-70% of that in cable, so about 5nS per yard or metre. So 30nS = 6 metres (ish).

Comment: @UmarMahmood in which case, no the DS1135 is completely unsuitable.

Comment: I need to do the processing on a PCB. I should have said this earlier

Comment: You could take a look at (for instance) http://micro.apitech.com/lumped-constant-delay-lines.aspx

Comment: It would probably be illuminating to share why you're trying to generate the delay.

Comment: unfortunately that is for a DC signal, I will be using an AC signal.

Comment: The lumped delay line that PeterSmith liked to is not for DC - it's for any signal with a frequency range between DC (0Hz) and 150MHz. It's an odd spec as you can't actually delay a pure DC signal, but it simply means that it will not block any DC component of the signal.

Comment: that makes a lot more sense. I think the link solves my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If money is not of concern, you could consider a passive delay line such as [these](http://www.allenavionics.com/GPDL/sp50.htm).

They claim that they can make delay lines with up to 30:1 delay to rise time. You are asking for about 13:1. Their standard products are only ~4.5:1 though so expect longer lead times and even higher prices.

Perhaps there is some other way of doing this than involving a delay...

Comment: unfortunately they do not have enough bandwidth. I'm looking at about 150Mhz

Comment: They say they can make them with up to 30:1 delay to rise time which, of course, implies a bandwidth of 350MHz for a 30ns delay. You claim you need less than half of that. I don't see the issue.

Comment: sorry I was looking at their standard products, the ones listed. So if it states the bandwidth if 50mhz for example a 10:1 delay rise time would mean it could handle up to 500mhz correct?

Comment: use BW ~= 0.35/tr (BW in GHz, tr in ns)

Comment: OK. I will get into contact with them. I'll mark this as solved